# Why does hdparm -I /dev/sdx give an error?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I wanted to know if my disk contains any HPA(Host Protected Area), by issuing the command 
*hdparm -I /dev/sdx*, but I am getting error

*/dev/sdx:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid exchange*

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the drive is named `/dev/sdx` ? Drives usually start with `/dev/sda` and go up from there, so you'd need to have over 20 drives attached to the system to get up to `/dev/sdx`

Double check that the drive is the one you're meaning to query (hint: Try `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/` to get a list of your drives with more descriptive names and to which drives the names correspond), and check that your other drives respond to the query.